# Role of weighted quantile sketch in XGBoost, LightGBM and CatBoost

Tags: boosting, catboost

Have i understood it correctly if i say that "weighted quantile sketch" allows XGBoost to use histogram search on feature values for split finding?

Also, do LightGBM or CatBoost use something similar to weighted quantile sketch? If not, how do they implement their histogram search?